# How to check if bluetooth is enabled programmatically?

Tags: android, bluetooth

I would like to check if bluetooth is enabled on any Android device periodically. Is there any intents that I could catch using BroadcastReceiver to do so, or is there other ways to do it?

Comment: Just check out this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html#SettingUp) for Bluetooth and follow all the step. I hope this help.

Answer (score 201, accepted):

There you go:

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
    // Device does not support Bluetooth
} else if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
    // Bluetooth is not enabled :)
} else {
    // Bluetooth is enabled 
}
```

With `uses-permission`

```
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:required="false" />
```

Comment: If bluetooth permission is only needed for this detection, don't forget to set it NOT required: <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="false" />

Comment: Is internet required to check bluetooth?

Comment: nope, you don't need internet to check bluetooth status. well, aside from getting the code from this SO post ;)

Answer (score 8):

Here I have other alternative as an answer for this question.

First add following lines in your Manifest file.

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.BLUETOOTH" android:required="false"/>
```

Now, where you want to check Bluetooth supportability, use following code.

```
boolean isBluetoothSupported = getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH);
```

Comment: how it's different with "BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()" ?

Answer (score 7):

```
public boolean isBluetoothEnabled()
    {
        BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
        return mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled();

    }
```

with the permission in manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

Answer (score 6):

To check Bluetooth state, ON or OFF, programmatically:

```
    BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = ((Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN_MR1)
           ?((BluetoothManager)mContext.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE)).getAdapter()
               :(BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter()));

       if(btAdapter==null){
        return;
       }
       if(btAdapter.getState()==BluetoothAdapter.STATE_ON){
            //Bluetooth is ON
       }
```

You may also listen to Intent action:

> BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_STATE_CHANGED

Answer (score 2):

use can use

```
BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
```

for check bt connected

```
mBluetoothAdapter.getProfileConnectionState(BluetoothHeadset.HEADSET) == BluetoothHeadset.STATE_CONNECTED
```

for check bt disconnected

```
mBluetoothAdapter.getProfileConnectionState(BluetoothHeadset.HEADSET) == BluetoothHeadset.STATE_DISCONNECTED
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it with the help of @xjaphx's answer, slightly simplified version:

```
 private boolean getBlueToothOn(){
    BluetoothAdapter btAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(); 
      return btAdapter != null && btAdapter.isEnabled();
    }

 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

Answer (score 1):

First allow the Permissions from Manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN"/>

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    
    private BluetoothAdapter mAdapter;
    private BluetoothDevice mDevice;
    private static final int ACCESS_REQUEST_CODE=100;
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_CODE=1;
    private AudioRecord mRecord;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        if (mAdapter!=null && mAdapter.isEnabled()){

        }
        else {
            Intent enableIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_CODE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode==REQUEST_ENABLE_CODE){
            if (resultCode==RESULT_OK){
                println("Bluettoth Enabled");
            }
            else if (resultCode==RESULT_CANCELED){
                println("Bluetooth Not permitted");
                finish();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: To check Bluetooth whether is turned on or off if turned off will reqest a runtime permission to enable bluetooth and if they deny the access it will close the activity.

Comment: If this post is an update of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65664087/4826457) answer, you should use [edit] link instead of adding another post or adding in comments

Answer (score 0):

Since BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter() is deprecated, you can instead retrieve the bluetooth adapter from BluetoothManager like so:

```
val bluetoothManager = context.getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE) as BluetoothManager
val bluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.adapter
bluetoothAdapter?.isEnabled
```