# Reading users choice in dialog

Tags: java, android, android-dialog

Is it possible to read users action in the dialog?

Example: On button `bttn1` click, dialog opens. If user clicks `No` in the dialog, nothing happens. If user clicks `Yes`, then `bttn1` becomes unavailable and `bttn2` changes its state from `setEnabled(false)` to `setEnabled(true)`.

General question but I am partially reffering to Bluetooth setup [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#SettingUp) where `startActivityForResult()` is used.

As current answer provides, it is about using `startActivityForResult()` and `onActivityResult()` but I still have no idea how to implement this in such condition.

I am not able to implement [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10407159/android-how-to-manage-start-activity-for-result) to overcome such problem.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is what you want, but you can create a dialog and listen to positive and negative button clicks.

```
new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
.setMessage("Deny or Grant?")
.setNegativeButton("Deny", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {    

    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        // Do something on deny click.
    }
})
.setPositiveButton("Grant", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface arg0, int arg1) {
        // Do something on grant click.    
    }
})
.create().show();
```

**EDIT:**

To detect if the user has granted or denied bluetooth permission, you should override `onActivityResult` in your activity and check the `resultCode`. From the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth.html#EnablingDiscoverability):

> A dialog will be displayed, requesting user permission to make the
>   device discoverable, as shown in Figure 2. If the user responds "Yes,"
>   then the device will become discoverable for the specified amount of
>   time. Your activity will then receive a call to the
>   onActivityResult()) callback, with the result code equal to the
>   duration that the device is discoverable. If the user responded "No"
>   or if an error occurred, the result code will be RESULT_CANCELED.

Comment: The thing is I want to refer to the already existing log. In my situation: http://developer.android.com/images/bt_enable_request.png

Comment: If it is just for bluetooth, you can check if the user granted access like by checking if the bluetooth is enabled. http://stackoverflow.com/a/7672404/812269

Comment: Granting access should make one of my button to become enabled for a limited time only. The thing is, code proceeds without waiting for users decision in the dialog. So checking the discoverability of the device right away after granting access is not possible as it skips the `if(mBluetoothAdapter.getScanMode() == BluetoothAdapter.SCAN_MODE_CONNECTABLE_DISCOVERABLE)`.