# Check if bluetooth adapter is connected to a wearable device

Tags: android, bluetooth

I'm developing an android app and I need to know when Bluetooth is connected with a wearable device.
I tried to use a method with a Bluetooth adapter, but without good results.
How can I program this method?

```
public static boolean btConnected() {
    if( /*Bluetooth is connected*/ )
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check if bluetooth is enabled programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672334/how-to-check-if-bluetooth-is-enabled-programmatically)

Comment: Does your app manage connection with the device or you only want to know if the bluetooth adapter is connected to some device?

Answer (score 0):

Add this permission in your Manifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
```

and create a method which will check if Bluetooth is connected

```
private boolean isBluetootConnected() {
    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    return mBluetoothAdapter != null && mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()
            && mBluetoothAdapter.getProfileConnectionState(BluetoothHeadset.HEADSET) == BluetoothHeadset.STATE_CONNECTED;
}
```

Comment: This would only work for devices that implement the headset profile

Comment: In case the condition with head set can be removed and can be used only the one with isEnabled before checking it's not null. `return mBluetoothAdapter != null && mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()`

Comment: that's not correct, isEnabled only tells you if the adapter is on, not if it's connected with some device. To manage connections you have to use GATT