# Samsung S7 doesn't; discover any Bluetooth devices

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluetooth-device-discovery

I am new to Android development, and have been scanning the boards for a couple of weeks now because I can't find any other bluetooth devices in my location.

I have included permissions for BLUETOOTH, BLUETOOTH ADMIN, and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION in my Manifest.xml file.

Hardware: REV0.6
Model #: SM-G930V

Answer (score 3):

Try to also add ACCESS_BACKGROUD_LOCATION and ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION to your manifest file. If that doesn't help, check that you can scan for other Android devices using other apps (e.g. nRF Connect) to ensure that there isn't somehow a problem with your hardware.

Some useful links:-

- [The Ultimate Guide to Android Bluetooth Low Energy](https://punchthrough.com/android-ble-guide/?utm_source=BlogEmail&utm_medium=Email&utm_campaign=BlogRoundUp&mc_cid=9113555d36&mc_eid=767bbcdc1b)
- [Location needs to be enabled for Bluetooth Low Energy Scanning on Android 6.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33045581/location-needs-to-be-enabled-for-bluetooth-low-energy-scanning-on-android-6-0)
- [Location needs to be enabled for Bluetooth Low Energy Scanning on Android 10.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58220159/location-needs-to-be-enabled-for-bluetooth-low-energy-scanning-on-android-10-0/58232014#58232014)
- [Bluetooth scanner not discovering devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65105856/bluetooth-scanner-not-discovering-devices)
- [Turn on Android LE scanning without asking user for permission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65795843/turn-on-android-le-scanning-without-asking-user-for-permission)
- [How to check if bluetooth is enabled programmatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7672334/how-to-check-if-bluetooth-is-enabled-programmatically)

Comment: I just wanted to emphasize that an app has to actively check if the location permission was granted from the user. This is described in 'The Ultimate Guide to Android Bluetooth Low Energy'. Great answer!